# What do I get with the default Backbone.Model initialize function?

Tags: backbone.js

For context I use coffeescript.  If I create a base model that extends Backbone.Model and I create another class (i.e. App.Models.Project extends App.Models.Base).. everything works as expected.. what would be the difference to an instance of Project if in this base class I wrote:

```
initialize: ->
  super
  console.log 'hi'
```

and just plain

```
initialize: ->
  console.log 'hi'
```

Without spending too much time, it seems in my console an instantiated object acts as expected in both cases.. I hear you should 'always call super' here but I don't know what I'm getting..

Comment: Backbone.js gives you nothing but a architecture **you get to decide what to do** that's it's beauty for example you can use initialize for implementing a Logic to determine the view based on input attributes,dynamically do something before anything else is done inside model and many more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone.Model.initialize does nothing.

From the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-35), you can see the empty function defined in [Backbone.Model](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-27)

```
initialize: function(){}
```

It's upto your model to override. Usually, model variables are set here. Whenever you create a model object, initialize is called internally.

The same principle holds good when creating Views and Collections too.